# Запись в файл с страницы с авторизацией

Tags: javascript, php, python, парсер, запись

Условия.
Есть сайт(нужно авторизоваться (делаю через браузер(хром), так как через запросы ещё не умею).
Адресная строка имеет вид:
'www.sssss.ru/test/tes1/1'
Моя задача - скопировать все поля инпут с данной страницы, и переключить на следующую страницу
'www.sssss.ru/test/tes1/2'

Все скопированные данные закинуть в Excel (а уж если есть проверка на дубли - то вообще красота).

Честно говоря, сижу и думаю, можно ли сделать это на js?
Дайте совет, куда копать.
Python, php, javascript - мои базовые знания.

Comment: Вам, скорее всего, не смогут помочь по двум причинам. 1 - Вопрос слишком большой, в один ответ не уложишься. 2 - Вопрос не слишком детальный, не до конца понятно, что это и зачем.

Comment: Цель - спарсить данные с сайта, без доступа к бд. Возможно, действительно слишком обьемно, но нужно хотя бы направление)

Comment: Направление - python ))
Залогиниться и получить сессию для повторного использования: python-requests
Найти в коде страницы все, что нужно BeautifulSoup
Записать в табличні документ - openpyxl